# Django Rest Framework Testing response headers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create automated tests and what I want is to check in my TestCase if there is a location header which it should be based on my code in views.py(Already tested it in Advanced REST Client). However, I can not to parse it in my tests.py

**Here is my code:**

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
url_1 = reverse('artists-list')

class ArtistTest(APITestCase):
    # Check the response if there is no data
    def test_get(self):
        # Checks the artists
        # self.client attribute will be an APIClient instance
        # Basically it will act as a client
        response = self.client.get(url_1)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        self.assertEqual(response.content, '') # There should be no data
        # self.assertEqual(len(data), 0)
        # print ("%s.%s DONE - 1" % (self.__class__.__name__, inspect.stack()[0][3]))

    def test_post(self):
        _data = {"name": "50 Cent", "birth_date":"2005-02-13"}
        response = self.client.post(url_1, _data)
        print "----"
        print response.headers
        data = json.loads(response.content)["data"]
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(data, _data)
        self.assertEqual(Artist.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Artist.objects.get().name, '50 Cent')
```

**P.S.**

Please be aware that:

```
print response.headers # this throws an error
print response # shows the header but I want it to be parsed
```

Answer (score 22):

There are several options:

```
>>> response.has_header('Location')
True

>>> response.get('Location')  # None if key not in headers
My location

>>> response['Location']  # KeyError if key doesn't exist
My location

>>> response._headers  # headers as dict
{'allow': ('Allow', 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS'), 'Location': ...}

>>> response.serialize_headers()  # headers as bytestring (in Python 3)
b'Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS\r\nLocation: ...'
```

Answer (score 4):

In case, someone encounters the same issue. The code to print out or return the Location headers is:

```
# url, just set your endpoint here
# data, just set the data that you will request here
response = self.client.post(url, data)
response["Location"]
```

Source: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4301#issuecomment-235224120